# how to addBcc in magento2 custom email template?

Tags: php, html-email, magento2.1

I am sending mail using below code. The mail work properly, but Bcc and Cc does not work. Please tell me how to set Bcc and Cc.

```
 class Dummy
{

    private $_transportBuilder;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder)
    {

        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    public function sendEmail($templateId = 1, $storeId = 1, $templateParams)
    {

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom('someemail@email.com')
            ->addTo('toemail@email.com')
            ->setReplyTo('replyto@email.com')
            ->addBcc('bcc@email.com')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`if($custom_email){

$this->transportBuilder->addBcc($custom_email); // Added for add BCC for custom dynamic email address

}`

Here is Updated code:

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
        ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
        ->setFrom('someemail@email.com')
        ->addTo('toemail@email.com')
        ->setReplyTo('replyto@email.com')
        ->addBcc('bcc@email.com')
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add BCC/CC to any email using below approach

Create a Plugin

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
      <plugin name="custom_welcome_email_bcc" type="Vendor\ModuleMane\Plugin\TransportBuilderPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin File

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

class TransportBuilderPlugin
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeSetTemplateIdentifier(
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $subject,
        $templateIdentifier
    ) {
        $bccEmail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_custom2/email');
        if( $templateIdentifier == 'customer_create_account_email_template') {
          if (!empty($bccEmail)) {
            $subject->addBcc($bccEmail);
          }
        }
        return [$templateIdentifier];
    }
}
```

Here customer_create_account_email_template is email template code.